# RBAC kubectl add/patch to existing rolebinding

Tags: kubernetes

Update: The reason for patching it to add a role to the rolebinding

Is it possible to add/patch to an existing cluster/rolebinding.

To save on obfuscation, I am thinking it would be nice to be able to add to an existing rolebinding.

Adding/patch to a role - I see as a a no go, but for rolebinding - yes please :-)

Tried [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-strategic-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment) but no success - so if possible, how to?

```
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test-service-account # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: ""
  namespace: default
  # core/v1 .. rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role #this must be Role or ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader-2add # this must match the name of the Role or ClusterRole you wish to bind to
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

And patched:

```
kubectl patch rolebinding read-pods --patch "$(cat rolebinding2patch.yaml)"
The RoleBinding "read-pods" is invalid: roleRef: Invalid value: rbac.RoleRef{APIGroup:"rbac.authorization.k8s.io", Kind:"Role", Name:"pod-reader-2add"}: cannot change roleRef
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: are you trying to modify the roleRef field in a ClusterRoleBinding?

Comment: Thanks, nope I am trying to add an extra roleRef - if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

roleRef in role binding is immutable by design. Hence you can not change it.

Here is the validation code:

```
func ValidateRoleBindingUpdate(roleBinding *rbac.RoleBinding, oldRoleBinding *rbac.RoleBinding) field.ErrorList {
    allErrs := ValidateRoleBinding(roleBinding)
    allErrs = append(allErrs, validation.ValidateObjectMetaUpdate(&roleBinding.ObjectMeta, &oldRoleBinding.ObjectMeta, field.NewPath("metadata"))...)

    if oldRoleBinding.RoleRef != roleBinding.RoleRef {
        allErrs = append(allErrs, field.Invalid(field.NewPath("roleRef"), roleBinding.RoleRef, "cannot change roleRef"))
    }

    return allErrs
}
```

Check the issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66353).

Answer (score 3):

You can patch rolebindings.

```
$ cat patch.yaml
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-new-service-account
  namespace: default
```

```
$ kubectl patch rolebinding my-rolebinding --patch "$(cat patch.yaml)"
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/my-rolebinding patched
```

Comment: Right, but then try with a reference to a role?

Comment: No, roleRef is immutable. You can only update the list of subjects that a role is applied to.

Comment: @Shashank V will it replace the current service account "test-service-account " with new service account "my-new-service-account"